# Large Form Layout for Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have to develop registration form in flutter which is very big but I am unable to implement it with the help of Flutter. This form is for a website. I am using `TextFormField` and I am unable to make it responsive.

[image]

Comment: Use Wrap and Row as its children, as you need 2 rows in web full view, make the width to width/2 or width/3 and check if the width is less than certain width (mobile screen size) then make the width size to full

Comment: Please share your code. It is impossible to debug your problems with out a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a form and in that form you put a column that contain rows in every row you put `textfieldform` or two as I saw I the screenshot and you should wrap the `textfieldforms` with the expanded widget and do not forget to use `MainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignment` to adjust your widgets inside the column and the rows and that should be what you need to do.